# Git Credential Manager - not loading when proxy enabled

Tags: git, git-for-windows, git-credential-manager

When working with corporate proxy - GCM not loading on clone/push from command line

OS - Windows 10 LTSC 1809
Visual Studio 2017/2015
Git for windows 2.21
Repo - Azure DevOps server 2019 with update 1(On Premise)
Proxy - Corporate proxy

I tried setting the Git Proxy but none helped

Only when i change the Proxy Setting on the system i can get the GCM to show
See attached images

in that case i cannot access the web portal - or use visual studio clone/push

[image: Default Proxy Settings]

**Clone Fails - GCM not loading**
[image: Clone failed on default settings]

**Web Portal works**

[image: Web Portal Working On defaults settings]

[image: Bypass Proxy disabled]

**GCM LOADING Clone successful**
[image: GCM LOADING]
[image: Clone Successfully and GCM loading]

**Web Portal Fails**

[image: Web Portal Failed Error 503 - with bypass]

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: look below my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add

**git config --global credential.{TFSADDRESS}.authority Basic**

The default settings is Auto

https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/blob/master/Docs/Environment.md#gcm_authority

When using Client(in work-group) to connect to TFS server(in domain) - NTLM or AUTO cannot be used